# The rollup outputs could be normal calls to L1 smart contracts. Who is the sender and origin of those calls?

Tags: smart-rollup, rollup, scoru

The rollup outputs could be normal calls to L1 smart contracts. Who is the sender and origin of those calls? I understand that anyone can execute them. Do smart contracts have a way to know if the call comes from a rollup output?

[Link to Twitter discussion](https://twitter.com/jagracar/status/1642173860551294976)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the L1 perspective, the source is the rollup address even though any user can trigger a smart contract call of the outbox.

Comment: Great Then one can implement entrypoints that can only be triggered when the source is the rollup address. I could imagine the rollup could trigger the mint of an NFT and send it to a given address. One wants to be sure that the mint is executed only when it comes from the rollup